# Arrays| Find repeating integers using array division?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

How do I make the method show the repeated numbers. It seems a logical error that is stopping me and I don't know why the code doesn't do what it is supposed to do.

```
  public static void findRepeating(int[] arr) { 
        for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
             for(int d = 0; d<arr.length; d++) {
                 if(arr[i] / arr[d] == 1) {
                     System.out.println(arr[i] + " is repeating");
                 }
             }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = {69, 7, 8, 9, 90, 666, 69, 420, 2};


        findRepeating(myArray);

    }

}
```

Comment: why not `if(arr[i] == arr[d])`? int division can return 1 even if the two ints are not equal. for example, 9/8 == 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your if condition logic.

```
if (i != d && arr[i] / arr[d] == 1 && arr[i] % arr[d] == 0)
```

1) You should check that you are not dividing by the same array element. You can instead initialize the value of `d` from `i+1` instead of `0`.

2) Divide by should be equal to 1

3) There modulus should be 0 because division logic is not enough for this logic. 
As @Eran said `9/8` and `9/9` will also result in 1 but with modulus check, we can ensure that we print that only `9` is repeating

```
public static void findRepeating(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < arr.length; d++) {
            if (i != d && arr[i] / arr[d] == 1 && arr[i] % arr[d] == 0) {
                System.out.println(arr[i] + " is repeating");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = { 69, 7, 8, 9, 90, 666, 69, 420, 2 };
    findRepeating(myArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correction, for the logic in inner for loop and the comparison

```
  public static void findRepeating(int[] arr) { 
    for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
         for(int d = i+1; d<arr.length; d++) { //check with next element, as u will iterate over same element if iterating from start
             if(arr[i] == arr[d]) { // checking for same number, as division can give 1 in multiple case for ex 11/7 is also 1
                 System.out.println(arr[i] + " is repeating");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton! May I get the explanation behind it? When i changed division to "==" it didn't work, why does the int i+1 work?

Comment: @sam, i +1 works , because you want to compare the existing number at arr[i] location, with the next (i+1) and onward.

Comment: @VinodSinghBist You are right, no reason to downvote (I did not). But mention the two small errors: / versus == and d = i + 1.

Comment: @VinodSinghBist Thanks! Got everything!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is already highlighted with your approach , but iterating over element again and again is not advisable when your array size is too high(time complexity of O(n^2) ) rather consider doing it as you iterate over the array in O(n) time with extra space of O(n)

```
Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>(); // to store elements
for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
            if(hs.contains(arr[i])) { // Checking if element is present in set or not
                System.out.println(arr[i] + " is repeating");
            }else {
                hs.add(arr[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to achieve this using array division but plus 1 for this approach :)

Comment: Thanks, Yea thought to highlight this, if it helps someone to explore new possibilities

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude current `i` index from second loop condition. For a large optimalization, you could start iterating second loop from  index `i`.

```
public static void findRepeating(int[] arr) {
        if(arr.length<2) { return; } // edge case condition
        for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
            for(int d = i+1; d<arr.length; d++) { // start from i+1 index
                if( arr[i] == arr[d]) {
                    System.out.println(arr[i] + " is repeating");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it will print:

> 69 is repeating

Otherwise you will always print `arr[i]` as repeated.